# Hacer un debug en Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

no se si me pueda explicar, quiero ver como Netbeans lee el código, para ir testeando que es lo que realmente eta haciendo con los bucles, creo que hace años vi algo similar en PSeint, cuando ejecutaba algo el programa mostraba lo que leia linea por linea, como una sombra que mostraba que linea leia y cual se repetia por los bucles. algo así necesito no se si en Netbeans tenga algo similar, muchas gracias.

Comment: Presiona a la par de la linea de código donde esté tu bucle. Te saldrá un punto rojo "BREAKPOINT" luego solo debugueas el codigo. Se encuentra a la par de donde compilas tu programa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En `Netbeans` como en la gran mayoría de IDEs, se puede realizar la depuración, en la documentación puedes encontrar esta información:

[Depurar y perfilar](https://netbeans.org/features/java/debugger.html)

[Uso del depurador visual en NetBeans IDE](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/debug-visual.html)

> **NetBeans Debugger** permite colocar puntos de interrupción (breakpoints) en tu
>   código fuente, agregar observadores de campo, recorrer tu código,
>   ejecutar métodos, tomar instantáneas y monitorear la ejecución a
>   medida que ocurre. También puede adjuntar el depurador a un proceso
>   que ya se está ejecutando.

Puedes dar clic en el lado derecho de la linea de código para insertar un "breakpoint"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para depurar puedes realizarlo mediante la secuencia de teclas <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>F5</kbd> o directamente desde el menú principal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

de esta forma la ejecución de tu código se detendrá en la linea que desees depurar (realizar debugging):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes ir linea por linea mediante la tecla:

<kbd>F8</kbd>

o continuar (se detiene si encuentra otro breakpoint):

<kbd>F5</kbd>