# String index out of range: -9 en java netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, string, login, interface

El caso es que estoy haciendo una interfaz para poder inicuar sesion en un sistema. Lo estoy haciendo en plan simple, la idea es que haya dos ventanas una para registrarse y otra para iniciar sesion. En la parte de registrse no hay problema. El usuario pone su nombre, correo y constraseña, y sus datos van a parar a un txt el cual se puede ver de esta forma:

```
Username:admin
mail:admin@gmail.com
Password:01234
```

Y ahora viene el problema, este es el metodo para checkar si los datos que pone el usuario coinciden con los del txt:

```
void logic(String usr, String pswd) {
        try {
            RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(f + "\\logins.txt", "rw");
            for (int i = 0; i < ln; i += 4) {
                System.out.println("count " + i);
                String forUser = raf.readLine().substring(9);
                String forEmail = raf.readLine().substring(5);
                String forpss = raf.readLine().substring(9);
                
                if (usr.equals(forUser) & pswd.equals(forpss)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password matched");
                    break;

                } else if (i == (ln - 3)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong user/Password");
                }
                for (int k = 1; k <= 2; k++) {
                    raf.readLine();
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RegisterPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RegisterPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

y esta es la forma en la que llamo a esyte metodo desde la clase cliente

```
 private void loginButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {  
                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:

           registerW regi = new registerW();
            regi.logic(userText.getText(), passtext.getText());
        
    }
```

Alguna idea?

Por upuesto esto es un fragmento de codigo que funciona con los siguientes metodos:

```
File f = new File("USERS");
String Username, mail, Password;
int ln;

void CheckData(String usr, String pswd) {
    try {
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(f + "\\logins.txt", "rw");
        String line = raf.readLine();
        Username = line.substring(9);
        mail = line.substring(5);
        Password = raf.readLine().substring(9);
        if (usr.equals(Username) & pswd.equals(Password)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password matched");

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong user/Password");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RegisterPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RegisterPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

void readFile() {
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f + "\\logins.txt");
        System.out.println("file exists!");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f + "\\logins.txt");
            System.out.println("file created");
        } catch (IOException ex1) {
            Logger.getLogger(RegisterPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
        }
    }

}

 void countlines() {
    try {
        ln = 1;
        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(f + "\\logins.txt", "rw");
        for (int i = 0; raf.readLine() != null; i++) {
            ln++;
        }
        System.out.println("number of lines;" + ln);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RegisterPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RegisterPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: Saludos, mm a simple vista puedo ver que nunca defines **f** ni tampoco **ln** imagino que son variables globales, podrias mostrar como obtienes **ln**??

Comment: Se ve que accedes directamente a posiciones de un vector sin verificar si existe o no.

Comment: Hola buenas, he actualizado la información. Como podéis ver en mi descripción efectivamente ln y f están declarados de forma global. Y para checkar la información tengo un método, como lo puedes ver.

Comment: hola @jojoji54, intentaste debugear tu codigo? sino es asi, aqui hay una guia https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/301955/131754

Comment: segun tu codigo en ningun momento le estas asignando un valor a `ln`, que imagino son la cantidad de lineas de tu archivo

Comment: hola buenas, como veis arriba a ln le doy un valor en countlines

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema segun tu estructura:

```
Username:admin
mail:user@gmail.com
Password:01234
```

es que no estas leyendo el password,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

puedes agregar un `readLine` para el email, y con eso ya puedes acceder.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que hace `readLine` es justamente leer cada linea del archivo en cada llamada.

te recomiendo que aprendas a debugear, hay una guia aqui https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/301955/131754

**EDIT**

Puedes imprimir por consola los valores ingresados, tu valor `ln`

tu metodo loginc quedaria asi

```
public void logic(String usr, String pswd) {
        System.out.println("valores ingresados usr:" + usr + "-pswd:" + pswd);
        System.out.println("ln:" + ln);

        try {
            RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile( "/home/user/IdeaProjects/StackOverFlow/src/login/logins.txt", "rw");
            for (int i = 0; i < ln; i += 4) {
                System.out.println("count " + i);
                String forUser = raf.readLine().substring(9);
                String forEmail = raf.readLine().substring(5);
                String forpss = raf.readLine().substring(9);
                System.out.println("usuario leido:" + forUser + "-" + forEmail + "-" + forpss);
                if (usr.equals(forUser) & pswd.equals(forpss)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password matched");
                    break;

                } else if (i == (ln - 3)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wrong user/Password");
                }
                for (int k = 1; k <= 2; k++) {
                    raf.readLine();
                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RegisterPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RegisterPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

la salida en consola:

```
valores ingresados usr:admin-pswd:01234
ln:4
count 0
usuario leido:admin-user@gmail.com-01234
```

Saludos

Comment: disculpa, intuyo que ese readline lo tengo que meter en el metodo de logic. Pero simplemente añadiendo un string que no uso no me termina de funcionar, una vez añadido el String forEmail = raf.readLine().substring(5); en el metodo de logic. Que mas he de hacer? Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: que error te sale?, he agregado el metodo completo, puedes imprimir en consola para ver tu problema, o debugear, saludos

Comment: ah, tambien podria ser que tu archivo logins.txt este en otra ruta. Usas windows verdad?

Comment: El error que me sale es el siguiente: 
number of lines;10
count 0
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -9
 at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1876)
 at FTP_Interface.RegisterPanel.logic(RegisterPanel.java:140)
 at FTP_Interface.LoginWindow.loginButtonMouseClicked(LoginWindow.java:161)
 at FTP_Interface.LoginWindow$4.mouseClicked(LoginWindow.java:89)
 at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:278)

Comment: el archivo lo tengo correctamente ubicado, pues me lo crea y me registra los usuarios correctamente.

Comment: y, he añadido el readline, pero no me termina de funcionar. Tal y como puedes ver en el codigo que he actualizado

Comment: Gracias por las respuesta Al final efectivamente el problema estaba en la estructura del logic.

Comment: @jojoji54 si esta respuesta te sirvió, por favor márcala como aceptada y considera darle un voto positivo.